# UIAlertView Showing Memoryleaks objective C

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, uialertview

I ran my app with the leak settings : Product -> Profile and then Leaks in the instruments menu.

So everything was working fine until this code runs.

```
- (IBAction)loginButton:(id)sender{

BoolSingletonClass *theBool = [[BoolSingletonClass alloc] init];



if ([_userName.text isEqualToString:_corUserName] && [_userPassword.text isEqualToString:_corUserPass]) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle: @"Loggning"
                                                   message: @"Inloggning Lyckades"
                                                  delegate: self
                                         cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                         otherButtonTitles:@"OK",nil];

    [alert setTag:1];
    [alert show];
    theBool.isUserLoggedIn = YES;
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];


}
else{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle: @"Loggning"
                                                   message: @"Inloggning Misslyckades!"
                                                  delegate: self
                                         cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                         otherButtonTitles:@"OK",nil];

[alert setTag:1];
[alert show];

}
}
```

It shows a leak every time the alert menu pops up in the application. What can i do to fix this? 
Thanks for all the help!

Comment: BTW if you are using Leaks, you can click (double click?) on the leak and it will show you the memory that it thinks is leaked.  You can then click on one of the arrows to expand a stack trace of where that memory was allocated.  It might help you debug what object was being leaked.

Comment: It's a bug in the simulator. It won't happen in an actual device.